# How to terminate FreeRTOS Simulation (no gracefull termination required)

Tags: c++, c, googletest, freertos

I'm trying to build an automated testing against my simulated FreeRTOS device

Gtest is running in the main thread, the FreeRTOS Simulation is started from the main Thread within a new std::thread.
The challenge is, that the FreeRTOS Simulation might start several threads as well.

The GTest main thread and the freertos simulation thread communicate via a TCP/IP localhost socket with each other (on a real device this can easily replaced by another socket). For a better overview this is not shown in this demo.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int res = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return  res;
}
```

and my testsuite looks like this

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <task.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#endif //WIN32
    class TestFixture : public ::testing::Test
    {
    protected:
    
      ///the Running Simulation
      static std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_pSim;
    
      /**
       * @brief Setup this whole testsuite =>only launch Sim once (and not in every test)
      */
      static void SetUpTestSuite();
    
      /**
       * @brief Trys to kill freertos (Freertos is not designed to be stopped once running)
      */
      static void TearDownTestSuite();
    
    };
    
    
    
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> TestFixture::m_pSim;
    
    void TestFixture::SetUpTestSuite()
    {
      //launch FreeRTOS_Demo starts some FreeRTOS Tasks and calls vTaskStartScheduler()
      m_pSim = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&LaunchFreeRTOS_Demo);
    }
    
    void TestFixture::TearDownTestSuite()
    {
      if (m_pSim)
      {
        /*
        * FreeRTOS is not designed to be stopped once started
        * detaching the thread will hopefully enable the OS to properly delete the
        * FreeRTOS Thread
        * */
    
        //stop all running threads
        const auto vecTaskInfo = getAllRunningFreeRTOSTasks();
        for (const auto& singleTask : vecTaskInfo)
        {
          vTaskSuspend(singleTask.xHandle);
          vTaskDelete(singleTask.xHandle);
        }
    
        vTaskSuspendAll();
        auto natitveHandle = m_pSim->native_handle();
        m_pSim->detach();
        if (natitveHandle)
        {
    #ifdef WIN32
          TerminateThread(natitveHandle, 99);
    #endif // WIN32
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    
    TEST_F(TestFixture, Foo)
    {
      std::cout << "Running Testclient" << std::endl;
      EXPECT_TRUE(true);
    }
```

**So my Question:** how can I terminate the Test and get the results from GTest. I do not need to shutdown freertos properly since this executable is closed after the test.

**What did I try so far:**

- I tried not to actually close freertos (I left out the
  TearDownTestSuite() part)). =>GTest Thread exit properly but the
  program seamed to be endlessly waiting for the FreeRTOS Tasks to
  terminate. Program does not quit.
- The TearDown() Solution posted above =>FreeRTOS Tasks still seam to
  be running. Program does not quit

could you help me out here? I know that shooting running threads down is not a nice thing to do, but since freertos is designed as an embedded application it is not designed to be terminated.

Comment: You can call [vTaskEndScheduler()](https://www.freertos.org/a00133.html) if your porting support it. Despite the documentation says that _"it has only been implemented for the x86 Real Mode PC port"_ there are working codes for other cores, like ARM.

Comment: Agree with Carlo, call vTaskEndScheduler to terminate the scheduler. As for other threads (such as timer, idle and user threads) change the code to check some flag. Otherwise you'll be stuck with some version of the pthread_cancel, which is going to get you in more trouble than it's worth it.